# How to check if balanced binary tree is perfectly balanced C++

Tags: c++

I'm new to perfectly balanced trees and I have some problems. Can you suggest an algorithm to check if Balanced tree is perfectly balanced tree? I could not find a solution to this problem.

Is this a Perfect tree:

```
     * 
   *   * 
  * *   *
```

Because the algorithm does not work well with it and says it is not a perfectly balanced tree, because 2^3 - 1 is 7 but the nodes are 6

Comment: The hits [**on google for this**](http://bit.ly/1m0C88w), some of which are on this very site, are numerous. A perfect binary tree is one where all child trees are also perfect through the leaf nodes. Do you want to know *how* to solve this *problem*, or are you rather looking for a canned *solution* ? One is an algorithm, the other is someone else's code.

Comment: No I want algorithm. I will write the code myself

Answer (score 0):

Check to see that the level count of your tree correlates to the number of nodes by this algorithm:

```
bool isPerfectlyBalanced = pow(2,binaryTree.levelCount())-1 == tree.numberOfNodes();
```

So that:

```
        *
    *       *
  *   *   *   *
```

Level count = 3, total nodes = 7

```
pow(2,3)-1 == 7
```

Comment: I thought a perfect binary tree was a full tree? What is the definition you're working with?